# jQuery div appear from right side of the screen

Tags: jquery, click

So I just made a div (#sharebox) with my share buttons in it. I want it to appear from the right side of the screen (as if it was scrolling from the right side) when I click the #Sharebutton.

HTML:

```
<div id="sharebox">
<div id="sharelist">

<p><div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-type="button"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')
    );</script></p>

<p><a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-related="jasoncosta" data-lang="en" data-size="small" data-count="none">Tweet</a>
              <script>!function(d,s,id){
              var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
              if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);
              js.id=id;js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
              fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script></p>

<p><script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">lang:en_US</script><script type="IN/Share"></script>
              <script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">lang: en_US</script></p>

<p><a href="http://www.reddit.com/submit" onclick="window.location = 'http://www.reddit.com/submit?url=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location); return false">
             <img src="http://www.reddit.com/static/spreddit10.gif" alt="submit to reddit" border="0" height=22 width=61/></a></p>

</div><!--sharelist-->
</div><!--sharebox-->
```

CSS:

```
#sharebutton{border-radius:10px;
text-align:center;
border:2px solid white;
color:white;
width:60px}

#sharebox { height:174px;
        width:80px;
        border:2px solid white;
        border-radius:15px;
        background-color:#03999b;
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 100% 45%, 0% 97%, from(#03999b), to(#262525));
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #03999b, #262525); 
        background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #03999b, #262525);
        background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #03999b, #262525);
        background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #03999b, #262525);
        }            
#sharelist{margin-left:10px;}
```

Comment: `I must make` is not a question. What works and what doesn't work? Explain your issues please

Comment: sorry. i used a fadeToggle on the #sharebox but it did not work.

Comment: `did not work` is not a detailed explanation of anything. You need to put a little more effort into concisely outlining your problems, and preferably referencing parts of code you have trouble with. A demo in jsfiddle.net also helps a lot

Answer (score 1):

In your css you should start the #sharebox out way to the right, with something like this.

```
#sharebox {
     position: fixed;
     right: 0;
     top: 100px;
     margin-right: -400px;
}
```

and then for the effect when someone clicks the share button, you could do something like this.

```
$('#sharebutton').click(function() {
     $('#sharebox').animate({left: "400px"}, 8000);
});
```

for more info http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: hi. i added your codes but it only made the sharebox disappear. but it wont appear when i click the sharebutton

Comment: thanks. i had my codes right. i forgot to put the scrip src tag in the head tag

Comment: how would it hide back? do I put

$('#sharebutton').click(function() {
     $('#sharebox').animate({right: "400px"}, 8000);
});

as well?

Comment: What I would do is have a small div in the top right hand corner of your sharebox that either says "close" or is an X... make that it's own div like <div id="close"> , and then do a sepearte click function for it like... $('#close').click(function() { $('#sharebox').animate({left: "-1400px"}, 5000); });

Comment: thank you. i tried all sorts of function and I think the best option for me is to do a click toggle funtction, without having to make a "close" div

Comment: sorry one last question. so now i have the toggle function. but how do I make the sharebox hidden first. when I load the page, I don't want the sharebox already showing.

Comment: in your css just put #sharebox { display: none; } and then put .show() before the animate /toggle . Like this $('#sharebox').show().animate({left: "400px"}, 8000);

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this by using newer CSS features like `transition`:

```
<div id="share">Content</div>
```

And the following basic CSS:

```
#share {
    width: 10em; height: 10em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    transition: left 2s, transform 2s;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

#share.offscreen {
    left: 100%;
    transform: translateX(0) translateY(-50%)
}
```

Please note that `transition` and `transform` will require vendor prefixes for some browsers. At this point, all we need to do is toggle the class on `#share`:

You can do this in modern browsers with `classList`:

```
document.querySelector( "#share" ).classList.toggle( "offscreen" );
```

Or by using jQuery:

```
$( "#share" ).toggleClass( "offscreen" );
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m383R/

Comment: i figured it out. I forgot to add the script src tag in the head tag